# Finding $m$ s.t $m^2-1=\cos (x)+\cos(x-\frac{2\pi}{3})$ has real solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

My work has found some bounds, but think there is probably a better way to tackle this, maybe without calculus. Here is what I have done:

$\cos (x)+\cos(x-\frac{2\pi}{3})=\cos(x)+\cos(x)\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})+\sin(x)\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})=\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(x)=\frac{3}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(x)$
Then maximizing $f(x)=\frac{3}{2}\cos(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin(x)$, we find
$$
f'(x)=0=-\frac{3}{2}\sin(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(x)\Rightarrow \tan(x)=\sqrt{3}/3\Rightarrow x=\frac{\pi}{6}+k\pi
$$
yielding the bounds
$$
-\sqrt{3}\leq m^2-1\leq\sqrt{3}\Rightarrow 0\leq |m| \leq\sqrt{\sqrt{3}+1}
$$
Throwing out some complex numbers. This is pretty ugly, any help would be appreciated.
edit: unit circle fail in first line $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3})=-1/2$

Comment: Observe in your first line of calculations: $\;\cos\cfrac{2\pi}3=-\frac12\;$ . Beginning with the rightmost part of that line I couldn't understand anymore.

Comment: I see that was my mistake. But what is the problem with the rest of the work? Other than that it is unnecessary for this problem

Comment: If you read my answer you will see this is *very* necessary to solve the problem, and if you read my above comment you'll see I couldn't understand the continuation of your work, with that "then" in the middle and stuff.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, had I used the correct value of sign i like to think I would have seen the easy trig identity. The "then maximizing" is just trying to use my erroneous expression, $f(x)$ where $f(x)=m^2-1$ to get bounds for $m^2-1$ is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\cos\left(x-\frac{2\pi}3\right)=-\frac12\cos x+\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin x$$

so the equation to solve is

$$m^2-1=\frac12\cos x+\frac{\sqrt3}2\sin x=\cos\left(x-\frac\pi3\right)$$

and thus it must be that

$$-1\le m^2-1\le1\iff0\le m^2\le 2\ldots\text{etc.}$$

Comment: oops, looks like i screwed up my unit circle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,

$$\cos x+\cos\left( x-\dfrac{2\pi}3 \right)=2\cos\left( x-\dfrac\pi3 \right)\cos\dfrac\pi3=\cos\left( x-\dfrac\pi3 \right)$$

Now for real $A,$  $$-1\le\cos A\le1$$